# 'Image' does not contain a definition for 'color' on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can't use Color on Image component.

Looked for solution but no luck. How can i use color on Image?

Here is the sample code that should work

```cs
public void Locked(GameObject go)
{
    Image ima = go.GetComponent<Image>();
    // Below line throws 'Image' does not contain a definition for 'color'
    ima.color = new Color(200,200,200); 
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have  `using UnityEngine.UI;` **not** `using UnityEngine.UIElements;` ...

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that code. Make sure to include

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

at the top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why they broke it, but now it works like this:
image.material.color=...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a `MonoBehaviour` that uses both namespaces: `UnityEngine.UI` and `UnityEngine.UIElements`.

The solution is to use full namespace when calling `GetComponent<>()`, like this:

```
img = TheImage.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.RawImage>();
img.color = partially_transparent_mix_color; // Renders MiniMap with transparency
```